# How to get the profile picture of user from Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to fetch the profile picture of a user from Azure AD B2C. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to fetch the profile picture of a user from Azure AD B2C

I think I understood your explanation, you want to get user's ThumbnailPhoto.

If I understand it correctly, We can use **PowerShell** to get it:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto -ObjectId '85a293bb-xxxx-448b-xxxx-c927991c26a2' -FileName jasonye -FilePath 'd:\adtest'
```

After that, user's photo will store to `D:\adtest`, and it's name is `jasonye`.

More information about this command, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduserthumbnailphoto?view=azureadps-2.0).

Also, we can use **Graph API** to get photo:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/xxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/photo/$value
```

More information about graph API, please refer to this [article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get).

Comment: `https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}users/{userod}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=2013-04-05`
Tried above url to fetch the user profile pic
`{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."
        },
        "date": "2017-08-08T13:54:05",
        "requestId": "9be0e61d-fb5e-4afc-9a91-317f8b30093d",
        "values": null
    }
}`
 
application uses MSAL to login to Azure B2C  that generates a bearer token,tried passing the same headers but didnt work.

Comment: @user1500960 I have update my answer, we can use Graph api beta to get the information, please check my answer:)

Comment: I have just tried with with a user which is not from onmicrosoft.com domain. it still returns me error. I have passed the bearer token generated via MSAL

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "08ac1c03-32c8-464d-b530-2488cbc5ddee",
            "date": "2017-08-15T12:27:02"
        }
    }
}`